# is there any open source exe solution for Java?

Tags: java, open-source, virtualization

looking for all in one free open source exe solution (for java ) that can be used to create an all-in-one EXE from one or more `jar`s?

**Edit:**
An "all-in-one EXE" is an executable that does not require a JVM to run.

Comment: Virus or not, there is no need to mention any commercial project in your question.

Comment: ok sorry didnt  know , but i meant like this product not wrappers
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following

- Winrun4J: http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/
- Launch4J: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: All this does is wrap the execution of the JVM, it does not create an all-in-one exe.

Comment: They can pack all the needed jars into the generated exe. So what exactly is an "all-in-one" exe for you?

Comment: presumably an `.exe` that can run without the need for a pre-installed JRE.

Comment: @Joachim: then Yishai should write so. If the question isn't clear the answers aren't very likely to be as well.

Comment: Yes, I meant one that doesn't require a separate JVM, not one that mearly extracts the project JARs at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

According to the project page, the [GNU Compiler for Java](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) enables the creation of native machine code.

Comment: its old , 1.4 , and mybe some 1.5

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jsmooth.sourceforge.net](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net)

Comment: All this does is wrap the execution of the JVM, it does not create an all-in-one exe.